# Pine v5 - How to make dynamic text in plot text?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

how to make dynamic text from input value into plotshape? Thanks

```
// Input
i_strat_longTPpercent  = input.float(title="Long TP(%)", defval=3) / 100

// Plot 
plotshape(longTPhit, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.purple, size=size.tiny, title="Long TP Hit", text="Long TP" + i_strat_longTPpercent)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. `text` arguments of the `plotshape()` function expects a `const string`.

You can use `label`s instead.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

var label l = na

if (barstate.islast)
    l := label.new(bar_index, high, text="Close price: " + str.tostring(close))
    label.delete(l[1])
```